# Can anyone tell me what's going wrong with this recursive function?

Tags: java, string, recursion, arraylist, permutation

So the question was to make a function that prints all permutations of a given string and stores them in an arraylist. My code was as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Solution
{
public static void permutations (String str, String perms, ArrayList<String> sets){
// base case
    if(str.length() == 0){
        sets.add(perms);
        return;
    } // end of base case

    for(int i =0; i<str.length(); i++){
        char currentChar = str.charAt(i);
        String newStr = str.substring(0,i)+ str.substring(i+1);
        permutations(newStr, perms+currentChar, sets);
        return;
    }// end of for
} // end of permutations() function
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<String> sets = new ArrayList<>();
    permutations("ABC", "", sets);
    System.out.println(sets);
}// end of main 
}// end of class
```

The issue I'm facing is that the ArrayList is storing only the first variation; i.e, only ABC and none of the others. I've been trying to find out the error for quite a while but cannot find it. Would be glad if someone helps out :)

P.S. Here is a code that does not use an ArrayList to store the variations and directly prints them. This code is working as it should:

```
/*Q) recursive function to print all the permutations of a string*/
class Permutations{
public static void printPerms(String str, String permutation){
    // base case
    if(str.length()==0){
        System.out.println(permutation);
        return;
    }// end of base case

    for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++){
        char currentChar = str.charAt(i);
        String newStr = str.substring(0,i)+ str.substring(i+1);
        printPerms(newStr, permutation+currentChar);
    } // end of for
} // end of printPerms

public static void main(String args[]){
    String str = "abc";
    printPerms(str, "");
  } // end of main()
}// end of class
```

Comment: Hint: compare your working code *very carefully* with your not-working code, particularly the `for` loop. How many iterations do you think that will execute in each case? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? (As an aside, I'd also strongly advise you to use more whitespace and format your code, to make it easier to read.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` only needs to be executed in the base case when all the characters in current iteration have been visited.

But in your example, code is returning after calling the `printPerms` function, so after processing 1 iteration for char at 0, it returns and doesn't process any other characters in the string.

Remove/comment the return statement in the `for` loop.

```
for(int i =0; i<str.length(); i++){
    char currentChar = str.charAt(i);
    String newStr = str.substring(0,i)+ str.substring(i+1);
    printPerms(newStr, perms+currentChar, sets);
    //return;
}// end of for
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The issue is in the `for` loop. Your code contains `return` statement on the end of the loop. When I removed it, code is working.

```
for(int i =0; i<str.length(); i++){
   char currentChar = str.charAt(i);
   String newStr = str.substring(0,i)+ str.substring(i+1);
   permutations(newStr, perms+currentChar, sets);
   return; // issue is in this line
}
```

Btw. my IDE shows me `Dead code` warning on `i++`.